# Cannot modify my USB Files/Folders

Tags: usb

This is my first post here, I hope that you guys can help.
I connected my USB on my computer (Ubuntu), but I can't modify its folders/files.  It says that I don't have enough permission. So I tried changing the mod with the terminal using

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/< USB NAME >
```

but it returns that it's read only.
When I put my USB on another OS it's the same! Please help! I want to be able to modify my USB contents on any OS.

Sorry, I would like to post images, but  don't have enough reputation...
But I can tell that mine is different than yours, it shows a warning sign, but I can see that it said that I might need two softwares: dosfstools and mtools, should I get them?

Comment: BTW: other USBs work fine, I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Than you.

Answer (score 1):

Open Gparted. Unmount your usb disk from gparted. Now repair your usb disk's partition.

[example: /dev/sdb1 not /dev/sdb. Repair partition not the disk].

[image]
From partition menu(P) and select unmount.
Again From partition menu select check.
Now apply.

Reinsert your usb disk.

**Follow the Instruction: [edited]**

Step1: unmount your disk [sudo umount /media/usbdisk]
       mount it with write permission [ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/meida/usbdisk']
       Now try to format the disk.[use disk utility]

Step2: [If first step does not work then follow the following steps]
Open disk utility. also insert your usb disk.
**Unmount the volume(m)**

[image]

**Now Delete the partition(D)**
[image]

**Create a partition. Then mount it.**

Comment: Hi Shantanu, thanks for your quick response, I understand the first part, I downloaded gparted, installed it, but when I try to unmount my device by right clicking, the unmount option wasn't enabled.

Comment: if it is disable that means your usb is already unmounted. Select check and apply.

Comment: I tried to check it, but hereis what it says: An error occured while applying changes See the details for more information.

IMPORTANT
If you want support, you need to provide the saved details!
See http://gparted.org/save-details.htm for more information

Comment: can you access the file/folder of usb disk[just read]? Can you unmount your usb disk with right click?

Comment: Yes I can access it, I can read it, I can even add files or folders to it, But I can't delete things from it.......................... oops! Before posting this, I checked, I saw that I couldn't even open it anymore, I removed and reinserted it, and now it won't even show up... I guess that this gparted made my day worst... :(

Comment: it's back now, I can read, add files or folders to it, but can't delete. I can't unmount it by right clicking.

Comment: first backup your data :)  open terminal, sudo chmod -R 775 /media/usbDiskName

Comment: It gives me a list of negative results, here is an example: changing permissions of `/media/OLIX/Programs/Reader 10.0/Reader/plug_ins3d': Read-only file system                                The name of my USB is OLIX

Comment: see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58914/read-only-usb-stick-that-wont-let-me-do-anything-to-it

Comment: I tried everything on this page, nothing seems to work...

Comment: backup your content and format the disk using disk utility(default installed) or on right click on disk. Do not eject your disk without safely remove(next time).

Comment: Still doesn't work... Still saying that it's a read only file system. I guess I know the reason, I tried to install the ubuntu ISO stuff on it. Then it started to give me these problems... I am dead.