# read only problem with usb drive and data loss?

Tags: usb, mount, data-recovery

I encountered a read only file system for my flash drive and I can't see my data (one folder which had all the data is empty).

I did `dosfsck -a /dev/sdf1`  (as I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58914/read-only-usb-stick-that-wont-let-me-do-anything-to-it)) and now I can write to the us drive.

But I can't see anywhere my data although the drive shows about  "3GB used" , "4GB free".

I have lost my data or there is something to do?

sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdf

```
Disk /dev/sdf: 8019 MB, 8019509248 bytes
102 heads, 38 sectors/track, 4041 cylinders, total 15663104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x04030201

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2192    15663103     7830456    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

ls -la /media/KINGSTON

```
drwx------ 4 me      me  4096 Jan   1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root  root  4096 Aug   3 17:04 ..
drwx------ 0 me     me      0 Aug   3 16:44 cc
drwx------ 5 me      me  4096 May  11  2012 .Trash-1000
```

Comment: Could you post `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdf`? the output of running `mount` on a console/terminal, and also run `ls -la` where your stick is mounted, (i.e. `/media/usbstick`)

Comment: @Braiam:Ok , I posted it.

Comment: Hit Ctrl + H when in nautilus and check the content of `.Trash-1000`

Comment: @Braiam:I already checked the contents of trash but they are only 313MB data there

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert but the problem seems to come from the 1/1/1970 date for .

You can resolve it saving file from firefox as indicated here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=141529. The date will be updated and the problem will be gone after remounting the USB stick.