# I Cann't Copy any file to My Pendrive

Tags: usb-drive

I can't copy any files from my Ubuntu (13.10) to Pendrive (Jetflash Transcend 8GB)
When I try to copy a simple file, it says -

```
*Error While copying to "Transcend".
*The destination is read only
```

I tried both NTFS and FAT filesystem. As I am new to Ubuntu, tell me in detail.

Comment: What filesystem are you using on your flash drive? NTFS, FAT-32, etc. And how do you mount the drive? By command line, in fstab, in your GUI/file manager, etc. Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: there is an Windows based solution described here: http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-684835-transcend-4gb-jetflash-write-protected this refers to Transcend's recovery tool and instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The following methods will often solve the problem and let you write to the pendrive.

- Change the ownership of the mounted partition (if possible) or
- re-mount the partition with changed ownership or permissions described in the following link

  [Mount a FAT32 partition in an SD card with write permissions for everybody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884562/unable-to-access-sd-card/884622#884622),

If it does not work, there might be another problem, which can be analyzed as described in the following links

- [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted: Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)
- [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a hardware switch on your pendrive enabling read only access. It's usually marked with a little padlock or "lock" word.

Otherwise it may be an ownership issue. In terminal:

```
cd /media/your_username
ls -l
```

and check if you have owner status. If not:

```
sudo chown -R your_username pendrive_name
```

Replace *your_username* with your active user name, and *pendrive_name* with your pendrive name (found by ls command).

Comment: I donn't understand can you explain more easily....

Comment: Which part? Have you checked if you have a hardware switch on your pendrive? It may be just a little button on your pendrive case.

Comment: I have checked my Pendrive and that is in FAT32 mode

Comment: The filesystem isn't the problem here. You are trying to copy via terminal or you are using Ubuntu built in file manager?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked on a 32GB (ScanDisk USB 3.0) on UBUNTU 16.04 LTS