# SD Card, Destination is read-only

Tags: sd-card

I can no longer write to my SD card using the GUI (Files 3.10.1). If I use the command line I can successfully write to the SD card, but using the GUI gives me "Destination is read-only".

Using the command line I am the same user as the GUI. No elevated permissions such as sudo are being used. I am able to write using the command line with the same user that is not able to write using the GUI.

I was able to write using the GUI just fine yesterday. There was an update(s) this morning to Ubuntu, not sure if that has caused this issue.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. To summarize, command line I can write, GUI I cannot.

**edit**: New test I just ran was to create a file using touch on the command line and deleting it via the GUI. I was successfully able to delete the file via the GUI. So I can delete, just not create/copy?

Comment: I'd like to know an answer to this. The only way I can copy files is via a terminal. I have no idea why the GUI complains but not a CLI command....

Comment: The following link *and links from it with more details* may help you or at least explain what is the problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/402236/i-cannt-copy-any-file-to-my-pendrive/939815#939815

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Cann't Copy any file to My Pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402236/i-cannt-copy-any-file-to-my-pendrive)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566595/read-only-file-system-on-several-thumb-drives) question; unfortunately I have not found an answer, but it may be worth checking out; I'd hate to have you go through the same diagnostic steps only to find out the same result.

Comment: Created a directory and changed the owner to myself all via the command line. Tried to copy a file into this new directory and still get the same error, "Destination is read-only". The drive itself works on Windows and has worked recently (yesterday) on Ubuntu. It's really confusing me why it no longer works.

Comment: I have looked high and low for an answer to this; I have ultimately had to use windows to check / fix mine, after that it works fine again in Ubuntu.  Unfortunately, mine have all eventually gone back to 'read-only' in Ubuntu, regardless of the method I use to copy files onto them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a USB stick Ubuntu 16.04. I could read the files but not write (even though I was able to delete files on the USB stick).

The solution I found was rebooting ubuntu with the usb stick in. The write permissions now work.