# Cannot mount usb drive as read/write

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, xfce

I need to pull about 13GB worth of data off my Ubuntu 16.04 box. I'm running xfce via Recovery mode. When I plug in my usb drive it mounts as read-only. So I do:

```
$ df -h
...
/dev/sdb3 ... /media/user/backup_drive

$ sudo umount /dev/sdb3

$ sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdb3 /media/user
```

These commands succeed. If I `cd` into `/media/user` I can see the files on the drive. But if I try to modify the file system in any way I get a permissions denied error. For example:

```
$ cd /media/user
$ touch newfile
touch: cannot touch 'newfile': Read-only file system
$ sudo touch newfile
touch: cannot touch 'newfile': Read-only file system
```

If from the xfce desktop I right-click on the volume icon and select Properties I see this:

```
Owner: 99
Access: Read & Write
Group: 99
Access: Read & Write
Others: Read only
```

Is it the "Others" permissions that's causing me grief? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at these links, one of them might help or at least explain what is happening, https://askubuntu.com/questions/884562/unable-to-access-sd-card/884622#884622 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: If you check the instructions in those links you'd see that I am doing the *exact* same things here.

Comment: Then the problem might be that the drive itself is read-only. Try the tips listed in the paragraph 'The drive is read-only' in the second link (in my previous comment).

Comment: I really appreciate your help but the drive is definitely not read only. I use this drive all the time across several different machines/OSs. Ubuntu is the only OS that is giving me permissions issues.

Comment: Well, then I suggest that you solve the acute problem with another [live] OS. Later on we can start debugging the problem with Ubuntu. (It could be that the drive or the USB system is disturbed by something.)

Comment: What file system is there in `/dev/sdb3`? FAT32 or NTFS or some other file system?

Comment: Your  Xubuntu unfortunately remembers a problem with your USB-stick - so you have to give the USB-stick an other UUID number!  You can use Gparted for this, under Partition the next  to last option is New UUID.
This saved a couble of my sticks..

Comment: Use my `pathlld` tool https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: What/who is the owner `99`? What is the output of `grep 99 /etc/group` ? How was owner `99` created? I do *not* recognize it as one of Ubuntu's standard users or groups. How was the file system of `/dev/sdb3` in the external drive created?