# Why can't I write data to SD Card

Tags: sd-card, read-only

I am about to upgrade hard drives and I was attempting to back up data to an SD card that I had used before flawlessly. The disks app said that it was read only, and when I put in a cat picture to test that, it didn't go in. I am a relatively new Linux user, so I do not know how to change the permissions. Can you help? I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Follow the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58914/read-only-usb-stick-that-wont-let-me-do-anything-to-it

Comment: You didn't format the card in Ubuntu did you?  Open a terminal and run `dmesg` and look for any error messages relating to the filesystem being remounted read-only and add them to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound stupid, but is the card locked? There should be a little gray switch on the side of the card. This caused me many headaches myself.

This is what a lock looks like, and where to find it:
[image: SD Card]

Sorry for the poor image, this was my *camera* SD card, and therefore the only one I had.
(I had to use my webcam).

As you can see, the lock is in the unlocked position.

Comment: Wow...
That was it. I feel so stupid.
Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem. I was running Homebrew on my wii and was about to smash the thing against the wall when I found this, don't feel stupid. Not many people know about it, and nobody checks to see because it's so small. Once, my switch broke off.